# Replace text with text from another file in a script?

Tags: bash, vi, bash-scripting

I want to replace 5 rows of text in a file with the text of another file in my script, I know that running vim I can do

```
:45,50d
:r replacement.txt
```

to delete 5 rows and then insert the entire file, but I want to know if it's possible to do this from a script & how? I've searched high & low and cannot find any clue how to do something like this.

Comment: Have you looked at using sed?

Comment: @MaQleod I didn't know `sed` could do multi-line, or replace with text from a file, I've only ever seen it with regex, could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e '45,50d' -e '44r replacement.txt' filename
```

To save "filename" in-place, use `sed -i ...`

sed can do lots of things. Here's a man page for it: http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sed

Comment: it took me a couple errors to realize `sed -i ...` didn't have elipses and use `...` as the attribute for `-i` like `sed -i ... -e '45,50d' -e '44r replacement.txt' filename`